# Magento 2.2 Programatically apply coupon code

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, coupon-codes

How can i apply coupon code programatically in magento 2 using cart id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe checkout session can be used instead cartId use below code:

Two steps:

**Step 1:** Define `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` in your constructor

**Step 2:**

```
$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->setCouponCode($couponCode)->collectTotals()->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code :

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

$couponCode = 'your_coupon_code';

if(condition true){

$quote = $cart->getQuote()->setCouponCode($couponCode)->collectTotals()->save();

} else {

$quote = $cart->getQuote()->setCouponCode('')->collectTotals()->save();

}